# Quarkus KafkaCompanion with avro message type and quarkus-confluent-registry-avro extension

Tags: quarkus

Trying to figure out why one of my quarkus test cases won't work. The test uses the smallrye kafkaCompanion, the quarkus confluent avro extension and smallrye kafka messaging. There are 2 avro messages being used, coverage and GraphCoverage. The message processing function looks like this:

```
    @Incoming("coverage")
    @Outgoing("graph-merge")
    @Blocking
    @Retry(delay = 1, durationUnit = ChronoUnit.SECONDS, maxRetries = 1)
    fun transformCoverageMessage(msg: Record<String, coverage>): Record<String, GraphCoverage> {
        val processorResponse = messageProcessor.processMessage(msg.value())
        val rewriteKey = processorResponse.euidId
        return Record.of(rewriteKey, processorResponse)
    }
```

The test looks like this:

```
import xxxxxxx.graph.coverage.GraphCoverage
import xxxxxxxxx.graph.coverage.transformer.mocksAndmessages.NextGateWireMock
import xxxxxxx.graph.coverage.transformer.mocksAndmessages.coverageMessageGood
import xxxxxxxxxxxxx.coverage
import io.confluent.kafka.streams.serdes.avro.SpecificAvroSerde
import io.kotest.matchers.shouldBe
import io.quarkus.test.common.QuarkusTestResource
import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest
import io.quarkus.test.kafka.InjectKafkaCompanion
import io.quarkus.test.kafka.KafkaCompanionResource
import io.smallrye.common.annotation.Identifier
import io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.companion.KafkaCompanion
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes.StringSerde
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import java.time.Duration

/**
 * Responsibility: <br/>
 *  <br/>
 *
 * Creator: xxxxxxxx
 * Original creation date: 7/19/23
 */
@QuarkusTest
@QuarkusTestResource(KafkaCompanionResource::class, restrictToAnnotatedClass = true)
@QuarkusTestResource(NextGateWireMock::class)
class MessageProcessorTest {

    @InjectKafkaCompanion
    lateinit var companion: KafkaCompanion

    @Identifier("default-kafka-broker")
    lateinit var kafkaConfig: MutableMap<String, Any?>
    
    @Test
    fun `Successfully Process Message`() {
        val topicList = companion.topics().list()
        if (!topicList.contains("dev-in")) companion.topics().create("dev-in", 1)
        if (!topicList.contains("dev-out")) companion.topics().create("dev-out", 1)

        val addConfigMaps = companion.commonClientConfig + kafkaConfig
        // Set up avro
        val covSerde = SpecificAvroSerde<coverage>().apply {
            configure(addConfigMaps, false)
        }
        companion.registerSerde(coverage::class.java, covSerde)

        val graphCovSerde = SpecificAvroSerde<GraphCoverage>().apply {
            configure(addConfigMaps, false)
        }
        companion.registerSerde(GraphCoverage::class.java, graphCovSerde)

        val prodRecsCount = companion.produce(
            StringSerde(),
            covSerde
        ).fromRecords(
            ProducerRecord(
                "dev-in", "Test Key", coverageMessageGood
            )
        ).awaitRecords(1, Duration.ofSeconds(60))
            .count() shouldBe 1

        val recConsumer = companion.consume(
            StringSerde(),
            graphCovSerde
        ).fromTopics("dev-out", 1)
        val graphCoverageRec = recConsumer.awaitCompletion(Duration.ofSeconds(5)).lastRecord
        // graphCoverageRec.key() shouldBe ""
        graphCoverageRec.value().memberId shouldBe "GOOD"
    }
}
```

My test application-test.properties file for the micro-profile configuration looks like this:

```
# Incoming coverage message
mp.messaging.incoming.coverage.connector                                = smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.incoming.coverage.topic                                    = dev-in
mp.messaging.incoming.coverage.auto.offset.reset                        = earliest
mp.messaging.incoming.coverage.value.deserializer                       = io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
mp.messaging.incoming.coverage.group.id                                 = ${quarkus.application.name}-consumer
mp.messaging.incoming.coverage.failure-strategy                         = dead-letter-queue
mp.messaging.incoming.coverage.value-deserialization-failure-handler    = failure-dead-letter
mp.messaging.incoming.coverage.dead-letter-queue.topic                  = dlq-out
mp.messaging.incoming.coverage.auto.register.schemas                    = true
mp.messaging.incoming.coverage.specific.avro.reader                     = true


# set the topic name for the channel to graph-merge
mp.messaging.outgoing.graph-merge.connector                             = smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.outgoing.graph-merge.topic                                 = dev-out
mp.messaging.outgoing.graph-merge.value.serializer                      = io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
mp.messaging.outgoing.graph-merge.auto.register.schemas                 = true
mp.messaging.outgoing.graph-merge.specific.avro.reader                  = true
```

The error I'm getting happens in the the call to companion.consume:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected 1 items, but received a failure event while waiting: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message. Only 0 items have been received.

    at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.companion.KafkaTask.throwFailureForCause(KafkaTask.java:110)
    at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.companion.KafkaTask.awaitRecords(KafkaTask.java:170)
    at com.hyphencare.platform.relationship.graph.coverage.transformer.framework.input.MessageProcessorTest.Successfully Process Message(MessageProcessorTest.kt:63)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.runExtensionMethod(QuarkusTestExtension.java:1015)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.interceptTestMethod(QuarkusTestExtension.java:829)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Expected 1 items, but received a failure event while waiting: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message. Only 0 items have been received.
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.helpers.test.AssertSubscriber.awaitItemEvents(AssertSubscriber.java:674)
    at io.smallrye.mutiny.helpers.test.AssertSubscriber.awaitItems(AssertSubscriber.java:442)
    at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.companion.KafkaTask.lambda$awaitRecords$2(KafkaTask.java:170)
    at io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.companion.KafkaTask.throwFailureForCause(KafkaTask.java:107)
    ... 74 more
```

I looked at the tests for the kafkacompanion in the smallrye repository. I didn't see one the was specifically for avro messages. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does it work in test mode (using the Kafka dev service)? Also, how is the schema registry started?

Comment: Hi Clement - Yes works in dev mode and processes messages. Also, tests using the InMemoryChannels work. The schema registry is started via the quarkus confluent avro extension.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a reproducer?

Comment: I have one, what's the best way to get it to you?

Comment: Hi Clement, there's a reproducer at: https://github.com/jjdestef3/test-avro-kafka-companion

Answer (score 1):

The reproducer helps a lot. The issue was that the first record produced using `SpecificAvroSerializer` (sometimes) fails because it registers the schema to the schema registry, which is not "completely" ready.

You can get the cause of
"org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message" by asserting the failure on `awaitCompletion` like

```java
companion.produce(...).fromRecords(
...
)
.awaitCompletion { t, _ ->
    println(t?.message)
    println(t?.cause)
    println(t?.cause?.printStackTrace())
}
```

Now for the fix, the most straightforward way I see is to assert a successful HTTP call to the schema registry URL at the beginning of the test, maybe after you create topics :

```java
val registryUrl = companion.commonClientConfig.get("schema.registry.url") as String
await.untilAsserted { get(registryUrl).then().statusCode(200) }
```

Finally, how you register Kafka Avro Serdes is correct but could be easier.
`KafkaCompanionResource` already registers `commonClientConfig` for test purposes. So you usually can pass that directly to the `configure` of your `SpecificAvroSerde`s.

And once `registerSerde` is called. You can use companion produce/consume passing the value type to produce/consume directly. It'll search for the registered Serde:

```java
// Set up avro
companion.registerSerde(PersonIn::class.java, SpecificAvroSerde<PersonIn>().apply {
    configure(companion.commonClientConfig, false)
})

companion.registerSerde(PersonOut::class.java, SpecificAvroSerde<PersonOut>().apply {
    configure(companion.commonClientConfig, false)
})
companion.produce(PersonIn::class.java).fromRecords(
    ProducerRecord(
        "dev-in", "Test Key",
        PersonIn("12345678", "Joe Smith")
    )
)
...
companion.consume(PersonOut::class.java).fromTopics("dev-out", 1)
```